# Wordpress child theme css missing

Tags: css, wordpress

My parent theme css is missing from my site.

I have a child theme setup using this `functions.php`:

```
 <?php
       function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'sydney'; //parent theme

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'RGUCCalendar', //child theme
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

My site's header is this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.9.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-bootstrap-datepicker-css-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css?ver=4.9.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sydney-bootstrap-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/themes/sydney/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css?ver=1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=5.0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='lsow-frontend-styles-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/livemesh-siteorigin-widgets/assets/css/lsow-frontend.css?ver=1.7.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='lsow-icomoon-styles-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/livemesh-siteorigin-widgets/assets/css/icomoon.css?ver=1.7.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-custom-jquery-styles-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/vendor/jquery/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css?ver=4.9.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-accessibility-css-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/common/src/resources/css/accessibility.min.css?ver=4.7.13' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-full-calendar-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/resources/css/tribe-events-full.min.css?ver=4.6.16' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-calendar-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/resources/css/tribe-events-theme.min.css?ver=4.6.16' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-calendar-full-mobile-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/resources/css/tribe-events-full-mobile.min.css?ver=4.6.16' type='text/css' media='only screen and (max-width: 768px)' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-calendar-mobile-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/resources/css/tribe-events-theme-mobile.min.css?ver=4.6.16' type='text/css' media='only screen and (max-width: 768px)' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-admin-menu-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/the-events-calendar/src/resources/css/admin-menu.min.css?ver=4.6.16' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-full-pro-calendar-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/events-calendar-pro/src/resources/css/tribe-events-pro-full.min.css?ver=4.4.26' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-calendar-pro-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/events-calendar-pro/src/resources/css/tribe-events-pro-theme.min.css?ver=4.4.26' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-calendar-full-pro-mobile-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/events-calendar-pro/src/resources/css/tribe-events-pro-full-mobile.min.css?ver=4.4.26' type='text/css' media='only screen and (max-width: 768px)' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tribe-events-calendar-pro-mobile-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/events-calendar-pro/src/resources/css/tribe-events-pro-theme-mobile.min.css?ver=4.4.26' type='text/css' media='only screen and (max-width: 768px)' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sydney-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.css?ver=4.9.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='RGUCCalendar-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/themes/RGUCCalendar/style.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sydney-fonts-css'  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro%3A400%2C400italic%2C600%7CRaleway%3A400%2C500%2C600' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sydney-style-css'  href='http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-content/themes/RGUCCalendar/style.css?ver=20180213' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='sydney-style-inline-css' type='text/css'>
.site-title { font-size:32px; }
.site-description { font-size:16px; }
#mainnav ul li a { font-size:14px; }
h1 { font-size:52px; }
h2 { font-size:42px; }
h3 { font-size:32px; }
h4 { font-size:25px; }
h5 { font-size:20px; }
h6 { font-size:18px; }
body { font-size:16px; }
.single .hentry .title-post { font-size:36px; }
.header-image { background-size:cover;}
.header-image { height:300px; }
.site-header.float-header { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) { .site-header { background-color:#000000;}}
.site-title a, .site-title a:hover { color:#ffffff}
.site-description { color:#ffffff}
#mainnav ul li a, #mainnav ul li::before { color:#ffffff}
#mainnav .sub-menu li a { color:#ffffff}
#mainnav .sub-menu li a { background:#1c1c1c}
.text-slider .maintitle, .text-slider .subtitle { color:#ffffff}
body { color:#47425d}
#secondary { background-color:#ffffff}
#secondary, #secondary a, #secondary .widget-title { color:#767676}
.footer-widgets { background-color:#252525}
.btn-menu { color:#ffffff}
#mainnav ul li a:hover { color:#d65050}
.site-footer { background-color:#1c1c1c}
.site-footer,.site-footer a { color:#666666}
.overlay { background-color:#000000}
.page-wrap { padding-top:83px;}
.page-wrap { padding-bottom:100px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1025px) {        
            .mobile-slide {
                display: block;
            }
            .slide-item {
                background-image: none !important;
            }
            .header-slider {
            }
            .slide-item {
                height: auto !important;
            }
            .slide-inner {
                min-height: initial;
            } 
        }
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) { 
        h1 { font-size: 32px;}
        h2 { font-size: 28px;}
        h3 { font-size: 22px;}
        h4 { font-size: 18px;}
        h5 { font-size: 16px;}
        h6 { font-size: 14px;}
    }

</style>
```

My child theme is:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   RGUCCalendar
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Sydney Child Theme
 Author:       xxx
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     sydney
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  RGUCCalendar
*/
```

I have themes setup like:

```
wp-content/themes/sydney
wp-content/themes/RGUCCalendar
```

How can I get my child theme to use the parent theme css?

Comment: Your parent style is loaded, see `#sydney-css`.

Comment: I have followed same step & code you given in the question & the child theme is working file with parent theme styles. Please check your file names & extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code I am using this code and it works in mine.

```
 <?php 
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);

    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-style') );

    }

?>
```